# Is there are way to set max supported version of eclipse for Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, version

A plugin that we are currently supporting is not working for last version of Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0).
Can we configure this plugin not to support this specific eclipse version and prevent it from being installed for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0)?

I tried changing Manifest file and set `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` to `Java-SE1.8` and putting a closed range of versions in `Require-Bundle` modules but that does not seem to work.

I am attaching my changed Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %pluginName
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.xxx.xxx;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-Vendor: %pluginProvider
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Export-Package: com.xxx.xxx
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="[3.15.200,3.15.200]",
org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="[3.15.100,3.15.100]",
org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="[3.110.0,3.110.0]",
org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="[3.10.300,3.10.300]"
Main-Class: com.xxx.xxx.MainClass
Import-Package: org.eclipse.ui
```

**Edit:**
The result from the change above is that I can still successfully install the plugin in Eclipse 2020-09 and I can still see the errors that are present if I do not use bundle-version attribute. What I want to achieve is
a) Plugin is not installed at all for restricted versions of Eclipse (In this case I want to be able to install the plugin for version Eclipse 4.11 only (2019-03))
OR
b) Plugin is installed but there is some notification that plugin won't be working for the last version of eclipse because it is not supported.

Comment: The required execution environment is not relevant. The 'bundle-version' settings you show would restrict the plug-in to Eclipse 4.11 only (2019-03). What does 'not work' mean? What happens, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. Added an edit to the question above.

Comment: I guess having `Bundle-Version: 0.0.0` and not incrementing it is causing it.